# PHP casting array to object inside a class. Is that possible?

Tags: php, oop, type-conversion

I have a variable like

```
$a = array(
       'first' => array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
       'second' => array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5)
);
```

To access an element, I can use

```
$a['first']['c']
```

But to access it like this,

```
$a->first->c
```

I can cast the array into object as follows:

```
$a = (object)array(
       'first' => (object)array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
       'second' => (object)array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5)
);
```

But i have to use the same inside a class like this..

```
class className {
     public static $a = (object)array(
           'first' => (object)array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
           'second' => (object)array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5)
    );
}
```

It throws a T_OBJECT_CAST error. How can i make it work, if i want to access the element like

```
className::$a->first->c;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constant expressions in PHP are rather limited right now (though there are some changes in the works). You can initialize the static variable after the class definition, or in a static initialization function, which you will need to call explicitly.

```
class ClassName {
     public static $a;
}
ClassName::$a = (object)array(
       'first' => (object)array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
       'second' => (object)array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5),
    );
```

The advantage of using an initialization function is that you can encapsulate other class initialization tasks. If there aren't other tasks, it can be overkill.

```
class ClassName {
    public static $a;
    static function initialize() {
        static $notRun = TRUE;
        if ($notRun) {
            $notRun = FALSE;
            self::$a = (object)array(
              'first' => (object)array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
              'second' => (object)array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5),
            );
            # other tasks...
        }
    }
}
ClassName::initialize();
```

Answer (score 4):

> Note that static member variable **shares the memory** among all objects
>   of same class

You can try this:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://codepad.org/5CI4kl0e)

```
<?php

class sample
{

     public static $a;

     function __construct() {

          self::$a = (object)array(
                   'first' => (object)array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
                   'second' => (object)array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5)
                    );
     }

}

// $obj = new sample();
var_dump(sample::$a->first);
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you can not use expressions in default class properties definitions. Only plain values can be used for that. In future PHP versions it will be allowed to use [static expressions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs) (*this RFC is by Bob Weinand*) in such definitions (i.e. expressions which can be evaluated instantly, not in run-time).

You'll have to use constructor to define your property value, like:

```
public function __construct()
{
   //non-static property:
   $this->a = (object)array(
           'first' => (object)array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
           'second' => (object)array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5)
    );
}
```

-for normal properties. For static properties, of course, you can use `self::`- but it will not be bound to instantiation (obviously, that's because it's static)

By the way, there's a trick with array to object conversion:

```
$a = array(
       'first' => array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
       'second' => array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5)
);

//object:
$a = json_decode(json_encode($a));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo {
    public static $a;

    public function __construct() {
        $a = array(
            'first' => array( 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3 ),
            'second' => array( 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5 )
        );
        self::$a = json_decode( json_encode( $a ) );
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();

var_dump( $foo::$a->first->c );
```